# compare-object in powershell, dosen't give any result

Tags: powershell, compareobject

I have two arrays and I'm trying to compare them using compare-object.

Aim here is to get the items that aren't in common. I collected the data in to two arrays `$result1` and `$result2`

```
$result1

customersourceid                    
----------------                    
126025db-fefa-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
16ace738-fafa-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
18adb12c-9800-e611-9448-00155d9697e4
1ffc4181-01fb-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
20c8e80f-3efb-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
22f333a5-d0fc-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
23fe0537-90fd-e511-9421-00155da64f13
33cf599d-79fd-e511-9421-00155da64f13
3804aee1-b8ff-e511-9421-00155da64f13
3d241b9d-7af6-e511-9421-00155da64f13
463c6b7c-cfea-e511-9447-00155d9697e3
463c6b7c-cfea-e511-9447-00155d9697e3
496794e6-4f01-e611-9421-00155da64f13
5d06f8b0-0cfc-e511-9421-00155da64f13
5dac4791-a400-e611-9448-00155d9697e4
645f4358-f4ff-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
6adb2433-0bfc-e511-9421-00155da64f13
948db8b1-7afd-e511-9421-00155da64f13
9f221d59-13fb-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
9f3b7de7-c7fc-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
a0a1b520-bbff-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
a5400d23-cdb8-e511-9446-002dd817030c
ab25269d-e5f5-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
d918513c-48fa-e511-9421-00155da64f13
e04e7304-f200-e611-9421-00155da64f13
f200813b-c8fd-e511-9421-00155da64f13
fecf2b1c-abfd-e511-9421-00155da64f13

$result2    
customersourceid                    
----------------                    
126025db-fefa-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
16ace738-fafa-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
18adb12c-9800-e611-9448-00155d9697e4
1ffc4181-01fb-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
20c8e80f-3efb-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
22f333a5-d0fc-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
23fe0537-90fd-e511-9421-00155da64f13
33cf599d-79fd-e511-9421-00155da64f13
3804aee1-b8ff-e511-9421-00155da64f13
3d241b9d-7af6-e511-9421-00155da64f13
463c6b7c-cfea-e511-9447-00155d9697e3
463c6b7c-cfea-e511-9447-00155d9697e3
496794e6-4f01-e611-9421-00155da64f13
5d06f8b0-0cfc-e511-9421-00155da64f13
5dac4791-a400-e611-9448-00155d9697e4
645f4358-f4ff-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
6adb2433-0bfc-e511-9421-00155da64f13
948db8b1-7afd-e511-9421-00155da64f13
9f221d59-13fb-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
9f3b7de7-c7fc-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
a0a1b520-bbff-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
a5400d23-cdb8-e511-9446-002dd817030c
ab25269d-e5f5-e511-9448-00155d9697e4
d918513c-48fa-e511-9421-00155da64f13
e04e7304-f200-e611-9421-00155da64f13
f200813b-c8fd-e511-9421-00155da64f13
fecf2b1c-abfd-e511-9421-00155da64f13
```

Here's the code:

```
Compare-Object $result1.customersourceid $result2.customersourceid
```

I neither get a error message, nor I get the result. Can someone help please ?

Answer (score 2):

The lists are **identical**, that's why you dont get a result. Per default `compare-object` only shows the differences.
If you want to see the equals as well, add the parameter `-IncludeEqual` to your command:

```
Compare-Object $result1.customersourceid $result2.customersourceid -IncludeEqual
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. I didn't notice that both the variables were pointing to the same data set !! Thank you !!